# After adding domain and ssl to orcommerce b2b site, I can no longer add items

Tags: orocommerce

after we updated the domain from just an IP and included a lets encrypt ssl to our site, the customers can no longer add items to cart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After changing the domain or toggling an SSL connection, it is required to change the URL in the [application URL](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/system/general-setup/application/#admin-configuration-application) and [Website URL](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/system/websites/global-routing/#sys-config-sysconfig-websites-routing) system configuration settings.